# SQL Server Always Encrypted with the JDBC not working

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, always-encrypted

I'm using SQL Server "Always Encrypted" - JDBC (Java EE), keystore is Windows Certificate Store but not working.

[create master key and encryption key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSBge.png)

[encrypted column 'StreetAdress'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trMPx.png)

[personal certificates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufD8w.png)

changed my connection (columnEncryptionSetting=Enabled;):

```
<Resource auth="Container" name="jdbc/BDTeste" password="xxx" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:sqlserver://almsql2019tst;database=BDTeste;authenticationScheme=NTLM;domain=xxx;integratedSecurity=true;columnEncryptionSetting=Enabled;" username="xxx"/>
```

error console:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.DecryptColumnEncryptionKey(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[B)[B
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.DecryptColumnEncryptionKey(Native Method)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerColumnEncryptionCertificateStoreProvider.decryptColumnEncryptionKeyWindows(SQLServerColumnEncryptionCertificateStoreProvider.java:61)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerColumnEncryptionCertificateStoreProvider.decryptColumnEncryptionKey(SQLServerColumnEncryptionCertificateStoreProvider.java:75)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerSymmetricKeyCache.getKey(SQLServerSymmetricKeyCache.java:130)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerSecurityUtility.decryptSymmetricKey(SQLServerSecurityUtility.java:161)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerSecurityUtility.decryptWithKey(SQLServerSecurityUtility.java:206)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ServerDTVImpl.getValue(dtv.java:3737)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DTV.getValue(dtv.java:247)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Column.getValue(Column.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:2054)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:2040)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getString(SQLServerResultSet.java:2511)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:887)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:887)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:128)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.getString(DBDictionary.java:1022)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.ResultSetResult.getStringInternal(ResultSetResult.java:556)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.AbstractResult.getString(AbstractResult.java:910)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.StringFieldStrategy.load(StringFieldStrategy.java:170)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.FieldMapping.load(FieldMapping.java:961)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.load(JDBCStoreManager.java:1156)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.load(JDBCStoreManager.java:1104)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.initializeState(JDBCStoreManager.java:431)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.initialize(JDBCStoreManager.java:326)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.initialize(DelegatingStoreManager.java:123)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ROPStoreManager.initialize(ROPStoreManager.java:59)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.initialize(BrokerImpl.java:1114)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.find(BrokerImpl.java:1072)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.find(BrokerImpl.java:994)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.load(JDBCStoreManager.java:1078)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.AbstractResult.load(AbstractResult.java:305)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl$SelectResult.load(SelectImpl.java:2535)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.AbstractResult.load(AbstractResult.java:298)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.InstanceResultObjectProvider.getResultObject(InstanceResultObjectProvider.java:60)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.rop.EagerResultList.<init>(EagerResultList.java:38)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.toResult(QueryImpl.java:1311)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:1062)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:912)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:843)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.execute(DelegatingQuery.java:601)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:297)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:314)
```

How can I use 'Always Encrypted' in project Java with keystore windows certificate without error?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your error message as text rather than as an image.

Comment: You seem to be missing a necessary native library, or have the wrong version of that library for the version of your JDBC driver (probably `mssql-jdbc_auth-<version>.<arch>.dll`).